# Fall Creator's Update - Lower Framerates

Tags: windows-10, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, windows-10-v1709

I am getting noticeably lower frame-rates in games, and the only change I made is installing the Fall Creator's Update to Windows 10.

In some AAA titles (such as "Rise of the Tomb Raider"), I had my frame-rate drop by 30-50% with no other changes other than installing the Creator's Update.

Any idea on which this might be occurring?  After installing the update, after a couple of hours I noticed I lost internet connectivity and I got a notification about requiring a restart to update driver hardware.

My NVidia drivers remain the same (latest):

**GPU Driver:**

[image: Nvidia Drivers]

**WinVer:**

[image: WinVer]

Comment: A bug in Windows or nVidia needs to update drivers for Windows.  As the Update just rolled out, there will be some rough spots.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths You would think they would have had this sorted out, as this is about to go into broad public use.  The "heads-up" time was significant here.  NVidia is not exactly a small company?

Comment: I agree, but as they say "sh*t happens."

Comment: @Patrick - You are using the generic Nvidia driver.  You need to install the current [Windows 10 WHQL](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/125516) driver instead.  I can tell this is the case because the date on the driver is Oct 6th but the release date for the last driver update is Oct 9th.  I also recall performance problems with Nvidia were also reported with the drivers included in the FCU update.

Comment: @Ramhound Amazingly, I tried this once but I tried it again now, and I downloaded a new NVidia client that has "Support for the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update".  So that was unexpected.  Yet it says my drivers are up to date.

Comment: It might take another update from Nvidia.  As I point out performance problems with FCU and Nvidia drivers are a thing.